# Initializing AsyncHttpClient crashes with ExceptionInInitializerError in Android Pie and newer

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie, android-10.0, asynchttpclient

In Android Studio 3.6.2
I get an "ExceptionInInitializerError" and "java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!", 
on this line of code:

```
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
```

Which happens only in Android Pie devices and Android Q emulator.
The crash doesn't happen on Android Nougat, Oreo.

Based on that info, I really can't find out why the crash happens. Any ideas?

Here's the logcat of the error.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.artificialsolutions.teneo.va.network.PortalManagerOAuth.login(PortalManagerOAuth.java:138)
    at com.artificialsolutions.teneo.va.PortalLoginActivity.loginUserToPortal(PortalLoginActivity.java:413)
    at com.artificialsolutions.teneo.va.PortalLoginActivity.access$400(PortalLoginActivity.java:64)
    at com.artificialsolutions.teneo.va.PortalLoginActivity$4.onClick(PortalLoginActivity.java:208)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry.<init>(SchemeRegistry.java:5)
    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultSchemeRegistry(AsyncHttpClient.java:209)
    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.<init>(AsyncHttpClient.java:176)
    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.<init>(AsyncHttpClient.java:146)
    at com.myapp.myappname.va.network.PortalManagerOAuth.<clinit>(PortalManagerOAuth.java:97)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: In Android, `RuntimeException: Stub!` usually comes from trying to actually run with an SDK platform JAR. That is the thing that `compileSdkVersion` controls. It gets included in our `javac` classpath to satisfy our symbols for compiling against the SDK, but it is not included in the APK. Instead, an equivalent JAR with real code is used when our app is run on a device or emulator.

Comment: @CommonsWare Interesting, How can I satisfy that requirement, so that I can run that code from Nougat all the way to Pie+ ?

Comment: Normally, what you are seeing should not be coming from a device, unless that device is terribly broken or your build process is terribly broken. Note that `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient` [is discontinued and suffers from security and other problems](https://github.com/android-async-http/android-async-http#this-project-under-develop-and-is-currently-insecure-to-use). Perhaps the way forward for you is to switch to something that is currently maintained, such as OkHttp.